# achartengine with fragments - Android

Tags: android

So what I am doing is, I have a dashboard which consists of four fragments in a view pager. The 4th fragment is a Dial Chart which I have made using achartsengine. I have managed to set the view obtained from the achart. But what happens is the chart moves to the extreme left of the screen. Upon many trials I observed that the chart moves according to the speed i flick the view pager. Upon reading I found out that If i convert the view to a bitmap it would solve my problem, but unfortunately, it just shows me a blank layout. Any insights on this would be really helpful.

[My Code](http://pastebin.com/FLv0Ykz1)